How do you snap to nearest face using geometry nodes
I’m trying to use geometry nodes to put circles randomly on a round surface cleanly (as in it’s curved around the shape of the round object)

(1) Could you add a picture of the surface ? I am not sure of what means "round". Is it round like a sphere, or is it smooth like a landscape with hills ? (2) What is the size of a circle compare to the size of the surface faces ? Is the circle very large and to project on many faces, or is its size of the order of a face size ?
